# How to Implement a SwiftUI Pop-Up View When Tapping on a Category in a Quiz App?

Tags: swiftui, popup, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm developing a quiz app using SwiftUI, and I'm facing an issue. I want to display a pop-up view when the user selects a category. The pop-up view should also allow the user to choose the difficulty level. I've tried using sheet and NavigationLink, but they haven't worked as expected. How can I implement this correctly and get the pop-up view to appear when the user selects a category? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Here is my code for the PopUpView file

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct PopUpView: View {
    

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var selectedDifficulty = "easy"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Choose difficulty")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)

            Picker("Svårighetsgrad", selection: $selectedDifficulty) {
                Text("Easy").tag("Easy")
                Text("Hard").tag("Hard")
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            Button("Confirm") {
               
                isPresented = false
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
struct PopUpView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PopUpView(isPresented: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Here is my code for GameScreen:

```
import SwiftUI



struct GameScreen: View {
    
    @State private var isPopUpVisible = false
    
    let categories: [CategoriesData] = [CategoriesData(categorieName: "Sport"),     CategoriesData(categorieName: "Historia"),
                                        CategoriesData(categorieName: "Geografi"),
                                        CategoriesData(categorieName: "Example"),
                                        CategoriesData(categorieName: "Example"),
                                        CategoriesData(categorieName: "Example")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Image("NewBgQuizUp")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                Text("Välj en kategori")
                    .font(.system(size: 36, design:
                            .rounded)).fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .offset(y: -300)
                
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 40) {
                        ForEach(categories) { category in
                            Button(action: {
                                isPopUpVisible = true
                            }) {
                                ButtonView(categorieName: category.categorieName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .offset(y: 150)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            GameScreen()
        }
    }
    
    struct ButtonView: View {
        
        let categorieName: String
        
        var body: some View {
           NavigationLink(destination: Text("testDestination")){
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .frame(width: 325, height: 90)
                    .background(Color("ButtonColor"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .shadow(radius: 15, x: -1, y: -3)
                    .overlay(
                        Text(categorieName)
                            .font(.system(size: 16, design: .rounded))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    )
            
        }
    }
  }
}
```